# Can attacker create encryption of message m XOR 1^n given the ciphertext c, in nonce-based counter mode?

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher, modes-of-operation, nonce

The following question is from Stanford cryptography course final exam paper.

> Suppose an attacker intercepts a ciphertext $c$ which is the encryption of a message $m\in\{0,1\}^n$ under nonce-based counter mode. Can the attacker create the encryption of $m\operatorname{XOR}1^n$ just given $c$? If so, explain how. If not, explain why not.

I cannot prove why that wouldn't be possible, although intuitively given it is a counter mode, I feel the attacker cannot create the encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ciphertext is plaintext xor pad. Since in case we want a ciphertext for a changed plaintext, the pad will not be altered since its not text-dependent.
Therefore, consider how would the ciphertext change if You add 1^n to the plaintext

Comment: It is still unclear to me. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: Everything that you said. I understand that in CTR mode, we have ciphertext C = M XOR E(Nonce||Counter), where E is the encryption function. Now we have been given C and then how do we find out E(M XOR 1^n) or is it asking us to find E(M) XOR 1^n?

Comment: You get C=Enc(M)=AES(Nonce||Counter) + M.
You want to find C' = Enc(M+1^n) which will be....?

Comment: C'= Enc(M + 1^n) = AES(Nonce||Counter) + M + 1^n?

Comment: yes, which means what for Your task of trying to predict what the cipher of M + 1^n will be?

Comment: Yes, so the cipher of M + 1^n will be C' = C + 1^n